# How get element by id using jQuery in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

How to get button's action in way like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view Ember.Button target="Welcome.booksController" action="loadBooks" id="butt_logger"}}
        Load Books
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

in js file

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('button#butt_logger').click(function(){
        console.log("Button was Clicked");
    });
});
```

or

```
Welcome.booksController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
content: [],
loadBooks: function(){
    console.log("Button was Clicked");
            //any script
    }
});
```

Both of them doesn't work((
I need advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [Ember.Button source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/button.js#L113):

```
Ember.deprecate("Ember.Button is deprecated and will be removed from future releases.
Consider using the {{action}} helper.");
```

Using the {{action}} helper, your template will look like:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <button {{action loadBooks target="Welcome.booksController" }} id="butt_logger">Load books</button>
</script>
```